# Encoding and decoding UTF-8 byte arrays from and to strings

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I'm working on a cross-platform encryption system. One of the requirements is to easily encrypt and decrypt strings in out application code.

The encryption class works flawlessly, but I'm having trouble with string encoding on the java side.

Currently, I have the following static methods:

```
public static String encrypt(String key, String data)
{
    byte[] decoded_key;
    byte[] decoded_data;
    try
    {
        decoded_key = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        decoded_data = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Not Supposed to happen.
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    if(decoded_key.length != 16) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key length must be of 16 bytes. Given is " + decoded_key.length + ".");

    try
    {
        return(IOUtils.toString(encrypt(decoded_key, decoded_data), "UTF-8"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Not Supposed to happen.
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

public static String decrypt(String key, String data)
{
    byte[] decoded_key;
    byte[] decoded_data;
    try
    {
        decoded_key = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        decoded_data = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Not Supposed to happen.
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    if(decoded_key.length != 16) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key length must be of 16 bytes. Given is " + decoded_key.length + ".");

    try
    {
        return(IOUtils.toString(decrypt(decoded_key, decoded_data), "UTF-8"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Not Supposed to happen.
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

My unit tests are failing when decrypting. I ran a test where I compared a byte array of encoded UTF-8 data `encoded_data` with `IOUtils.toString(`encoded_data`, "UTF-8").getBytes("UTF-8")` and for some reason they turned out to be different arrays altogether. No wonder my decryption algorithm is failing.

What is the proper procedure to convert from a java string to a UTF-8 byte array and back to a java string?

Comment: why are you representing your "keys" as Strings in the first place?  presumably they are arbitrary bytes?  you are probably corrupting your keys by converting them into Strings in the first place.

Comment: business requirement. My encryption class uses bytes.

Comment: you're missing my point.  how are you maintaining the keys as strings without corrupting them?

Comment: @jtahlborn maybe the key is alphanumeric? I would see a problem if he tries to convert the encrypted raw bytes to a string.

Comment: @jtahlborn If I was maintaining string integrity I wouldn't be asking this question in the first place. It's not the keys giving me trouble here. Alex is correct, the string is always going to be alphanumeric.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code which is converting from bytes to Strings using UTF-8.

Comment: are you reading your data from a file before working with it?  if so, are you specifying the charset in that operation?

Comment: @jtahlborn there is. Otherwise IOUtils.toString(encoded_data, "UTF-8").getBytes("UTF-8") would be the same as encoded_data, which it isn't. I think that's the problem.

Comment: you're welcome to think that, however, i repeat, there's nothing wrong with the conversions in the currently included code.

Comment: @jtahlborn I wrote a test to prove you wrong and then all of sudden it passed every single test. This doesn't make sense!

Comment: @jtahlborn it seems the problem occurs with the encrypted byte array, after it gets converted back into a string.

Comment: are you doing anything with the String between encrypt and decrypt or are you passing straight from one method to the other? (i.e. are you writing it to some sort of storage like disk/db)?

Comment: @jtahlborn Basically: string -> UTF-8 -> Encrypted data -> string. Exactly as seen in the code. It's AES encryption underneath.

Comment: **A UTF-8 byte sequence has special rules to the allowed bytes.** So not any byte sequence can be represented as UTF-8 String. For instance `new byte[] { (byte)0x8f }` as 0b10xxxxxx is a continuation byte.

Comment: @JoopEggen - yep, that's the problem.  just finished writing it up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that you are converting your encrypted data to a String.  encrypted data is binary, not String data.  UTF-8 is a charset with a specific encoding format.  arbitrary binary data is *not* valid UTF-8 data.  when you convert the encrypted data into a String, the "invalid" characters are most likely getting replaced with the `?` invalid char.

If you want to convert arbitrary binary data (aka encrypted data) into a String, you need to use some binary->text conversion like Base64.

Comment: I added an example to your answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try out checking first that the output of your encrypt method matches the one you are expecting with a unit test.

Also it's a good idea to use Base64 after the encryption so you can convert it to a string.

Another common issue is converting int to bytes as if they were unsigned ints. Bytes range is -128 to 127.

Comment: the methods aren't recursive, they take Strings, they call methods taking byte[]s.

Comment: Oops you are right that's a strange use of polymorphism over there. I imagine that there are some duplicate code/checks on the other method.

Comment: It's not strange at all, they are both decrypt, but for different types of parameters. The string version prepares everything for the byte array method.

Comment: @elite5472 `if(decoded_key.length != 16)` should be checked on your byte accepting method. And I'm pretty sure you are already doing it in there as well.

Comment: @Alex this isn't production code. I'm still working on it. I needed to check if string encoding is working correctly before anything else.

Comment: @elite5472 edited the answer, try to do what I say after the recursive point. I had a similar issue not long ago and that's how I fixed it.

Comment: @Alex the method is not recursive, the base class is already tested, I'm never dealing with integer numbers in any of these methods.

Comment: @elite5472 I'm curious. Did you actually read my answer before accepting the other one? From the beginning I told you to Base64 your encrypted string PLUS that you need to be sure when using bytes because their are signed.